# C# Windows Form, hacer un picturebox con background transparente

Tags: c#, picturebox

Esta es la cuestión, estoy realizando un editor de vista previa donde posiciono un logo sobre un pieza textil. En un formulario tengo 2 picturebox, el grande donde esta la imagen de molde (pantalón) y la segunda el logo que quiero colocar a manera de vista previa. el problema son las imágenes transparentes que muestran el background del color del picturebox. Abra una manera de que el fondo del picturebox no se vea?

Ya comprobé y la imagen si es transparente y aun así se ve el el fondo del picturebox

El usar background color transparent tampoco funciona ya que toma el color del formulario padre (gris)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy bucando se que vea asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se esto ayude pero la imagen donde ira el logo puede moverse y cambiar de tamaño en runtime usando lo siguente:

```
private void piece_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        draggedPiece = sender as Control;

        if ((e.X <= resizingMargin) || (e.X >= draggedPiece.Width - resizingMargin) ||
            (e.Y <= resizingMargin) || (e.Y >= draggedPiece.Height - resizingMargin))
        {
            resizing = true;

            // indicate resizing
            this.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNWSE;

            // starting size
            this.startSize = new Size(e.X, e.Y);
            // get the location of the picture box
            Point pt = this.PointToScreen(draggedPiece.Location);
            rectProposedSize = new Rectangle(pt, startSize);
            // draw rect
            ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(rectProposedSize, this.ForeColor, FrameStyle.Dashed);
        }
        else
        {
            resizing = false;
            // indicate moving
            this.Cursor = Cursors.SizeAll;
        }

        // start point location
        this.startDraggingPoint = e.Location;
    }

    private void piece_MouseMove_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (draggedPiece != null)
        {
            if (resizing)
            {
                // erase rect
                if (rectProposedSize.Width > 0 && rectProposedSize.Height > 0)
                    ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(rectProposedSize, this.ForeColor, FrameStyle.Dashed);
                // calculate rect new size
                rectProposedSize.Width = e.X - this.startDraggingPoint.X + this.startSize.Width;
                rectProposedSize.Height = e.Y - this.startDraggingPoint.Y + this.startSize.Height;
                // draw rect
                if (rectProposedSize.Width > 0 && rectProposedSize.Height > 0)
                    ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(rectProposedSize, this.ForeColor, FrameStyle.Dashed);
            }
            else
            {
                Point pt;
                if (draggedPiece == sender)
                    pt = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
                else
                    pt = draggedPiece.PointToClient((sender as Control).PointToScreen(new Point(e.X, e.Y)));

                draggedPiece.Left += pt.X - this.startDraggingPoint.X;
                draggedPiece.Top += pt.Y - this.startDraggingPoint.Y;
            }
        }
    }

    private void piece_MouseUp_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (resizing)
        {
            if (rectProposedSize.Width > 0 && rectProposedSize.Height > 0)
            {
                // erase rect
                ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(rectProposedSize, this.ForeColor, FrameStyle.Dashed);
            }
            // compare to min width and size ?
            if (rectProposedSize.Width > 10 && rectProposedSize.Height > 10)
            {
                // set size 
                this.draggedPiece.Size = rectProposedSize.Size;
            }
            else
            {
                // you might want to set some minimal size here
                this.draggedPiece.Size = new Size((int)Math.Max(10, rectProposedSize.Width), Math.Max(10, rectProposedSize.Height));
            }
        }

        this.draggedPiece = null;
        this.startDraggingPoint = Point.Empty;
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }
```

Comment: aclara si es winforms o wpf porfa!